# Creating Violin plots in spotfire

Tags: spotfire

Can we create violin plots in Tibco Spotfire?
I tried searching for it on the website but could not find anything. Is there customized code out there that I can implement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By taking advantage of the JSViz plugin for Spotfire, you can link to and create any JS Viz that is out there. In the linked example, they create a D3 Funnel Chart: https://community.tibco.com/wiki/tibco-spotfire-funnel-chart-using-jsviz

Looking at the D3 Graph Gallery, they have a Violin Chart you could plug into Spotfire instead: https://www.d3-graph-gallery.com/violin

I recommend downloading the sample .dxp from the Spotfire link that starts with the Funnel Graph from D3, and converting it to a Violin Chart example. Then try to implement it with your data.